# find distribution of $\max(x^2,x)$ and $\min (x,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have the following question.

Find distribution of $Y=\max(X^2,X)$ and $Z=\min(X,1)$.

My distribution function is

$$
F_X(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \mathrm{if}\; x <0\\
0.5x &  \mathrm{if}\; x \in [0,2]\\
1 &  \mathrm{if}\; x>2\\
\end{array}\right.
$$

so $F_Y=P(X^2 \le t)P(X \le t)=(F_X(\sqrt{t}) - F_X(-\sqrt{t}))F_X(t)$

$F_Z=1-(1-F_X(t))(1-P(1<t))$

What is $ P(1<t)$? How to write it in terms of my distribution function?

And how to finish $F_Y$?

Comment: Your function $f(x)$ cannot be a true distribution function because it has infinite integral over $x$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Its the distribution function, **not** the density. $X$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,2]$.

Comment: I edited and wrote $F_X$ instead of $f$ as usually $f$ is used to indicate a density. One is so used to this that can easily be confused ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In calculating $F_Y$, you did wrong. Note that $X^2$ and $X$ are not independent. But $X^2 \le X$ iff $X \le 1$. We have for $t \in [0,1]$: 
\begin{align*}
  \def\P{\mathbf P}\P(Y \le t) &= \P(X \le t)\\
                &= \frac 12 t\\
\end{align*}
and for $t \in [1,4]$:
\begin{align*}
  \P(Y \le t) &= \P(Y \le 1) + \P(1 < Y \le t)\\
              &= \P(X \le 1) + \P(1 < X^2 \le t)\\
              &= \frac 12 + \P(1 < X \le \sqrt t)\\
              &= \frac 12 + \frac 12\sqrt t - \frac 12\\
              &= \frac 12 \sqrt t
\end{align*}
Hence 
$$ 
 F_Y(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & t \le 0 \\
                        \frac 12 t & t \in [0,1]\\
                        \frac 12 \sqrt t & t \in [1,4]\\
                        1 & t \ge 4
\end{cases}
$$
For $Z$ we have that $Z = 1$ iff $X \ge 1$, $Z=X$ otherwise. Hence for $t \in [0,1)$, we have
\begin{align*}
  \P(Z \le t) &= \P(X \le t)\\
              &= \frac 12 t 
\end{align*}
for any $t \ge 1$, we have as $Z \le 1$ holds always,
\begin{align*}
  \P(Z \le t) &= \P(X \le 1)\\
              &= 1 
\end{align*}
Hence 
$$ 
 F_Z(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & t \le 0 \\
                        \frac 12 t & t \in [0,1)\\
                        1 & t \ge 1
\end{cases}
$$